# Display Tree results on single line Python

Tags: python-2.7, tree, export-to-csv, pretty-print

I'm very new to Python and am trying to export data from REST API in Python.

I'm struggling at the moment on rolling up a tree results to display on 1 line.

Using pretty print. I get the data looking like this:

```
[data]
  [[fields_descriptions]]
    Field 1 : Description
    Field 2 : Description
    Field 3 : Description
    Field 4 : Description
    Field 5 : Description
  fields : [u'lField 1', u'Field 2', u'Field 3', u'Field 4', u'Field 5']
  aggregated_window : None
  locations
    [[[{Place]]]
      [[[[network]]]]
        id : 460
        label : Label 1
      id : 1424
      label : Label 2
    id : 9263
    label : Label 3
```

I then want to export it to CSV below what is currently in the csv, and have it display as:

```
Field 1, Field 2, Field 3, Field 4, Field 5, Label 1, Label 2, Label 3
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Thank you so much!

P.S This is my PrettyPrint

```
def prettyPrint(dictionary, ident = '', braces=1):
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print '%s%s%s%s' % (ident, braces*'[', key, braces*']')
            prettyPrint(value, ident+'  ', braces+1)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            ndict=0
            for v in value:
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    ndict += 1
            if ndict:
                print '%s%s' % (ident, key)
                for e in value:
                    if isinstance(e, dict):
                        prettyPrint(e, ident+'  ', braces+1)
                    else:
                         print ident+'%s : %s' %(key, e)
            else:
                print ident+'%s : %s' %(key, value)
        else:
            print ident+'%s : %s' %(key, value)
```